# Combine name of couple considering person hierarchy Ancestor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This one might be a little complex so I've provided a mock data:

```
declare @SupervisorID uniqueidentifier, @SupervisorNode hierarchyid

create table #Person(
PersonID uniqueidentifier primary key,
FirstName varchar(max),
LastName varchar(max),
EmployedOn datetime,
ID int Identity(1,1)    -- this is not a relevant column to the query needed and should not be included
)
create table #PersonOrg (
PersonID uniqueidentifier references #Person(PersonID),
PersonNode hierarchyid
)

create table #PersonRelationship (
    PersonID uniqueidentifier references #Person(PersonID),
    RelatedPersonID uniqueidentifier,
    RelationshipType int --spouse is type 3
)


insert into #Person values 
(newid(), 'John', 'Doe', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Jane', 'Doe', '02/01/2013'), --John Doe's wife
(newid(), 'John', 'Wayne', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Sherry', 'Wayne', '12/01/2012'), --John Wayne's wife
(newid(), 'Carl', 'Malone', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Tom', 'No Wife', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Cherry', 'Irrelevant', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Jenny', 'Earhart', '01/02/2013'), --Carl Malone's Wife
(newid(), 'Eric', 'Morales', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Sheldon', 'Marley', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Supervisor', 'One', '01/01/2013'),
(newid(), 'Supervisor', 'Two', '01/01/2013')


insert into #PersonOrg
select PersonID, '/1/' from #Person where FirstName = 'Supervisor' and LastName = 'One'

insert into #PersonOrg
select PersonID, '/2/' from #Person where FirstName = 'Supervisor' and LastName = 'Two'


INSERT INTO #PersonOrg
Select PersonID, '/1/' + CONVERT(varchar(max), ID) + '/' from #Person
WHERE PersonID not in (select PersonID from #PersonOrg)
AND ID not in (4,8)

INSERT INTO #PersonOrg
Select PersonID, '/2/' + CONVERT(varchar(max), ID) + '/' from #Person
WHERE PersonID not in (select PersonID from #PersonOrg)
ORDER BY ID

--alter table #PersonOrg drop column ID

insert into #PersonRelationship
Select PersonID, newid(), 3 from #Person p --the newid will be replaced with the actual spouse id
WHERE p.PersonID not in (select PersonID from #PersonRelationship)
AND (
    (FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Doe') OR
    (FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Wayne') OR
    (FirstName = 'Carl' AND LastName = 'Malone') OR
    (FirstName = 'Jane' AND LastName = 'Doe') OR
    (FirstName = 'Sherry' AND LastName = 'Wayne') OR
    (FirstName = 'Jenny' AND LastName = 'Earhart')
)

update #PersonRelationship set RelatedPersonID = (SELECT PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Jane' and LastName = 'Doe')
WHERE PersonID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Doe')

update #PersonRelationship set RelatedPersonID = (SELECT PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Sherry' and LastName = 'Wayne')
WHERE PersonID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Wayne')

update #PersonRelationship set RelatedPersonID = (SELECT PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Jenny' and LastName = 'Earhart')
WHERE PersonID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Carl' and LastName = 'Malone')

--
update #PersonRelationship set RelatedPersonID = (SELECT PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Doe')
WHERE PersonID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Jane' and LastName = 'Doe')

update #PersonRelationship set RelatedPersonID = (SELECT PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Wayne')
WHERE PersonID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Sherry' and LastName = 'Wayne')

update #PersonRelationship set RelatedPersonID = (SELECT PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Carl' and LastName = 'Malone')
WHERE PersonID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Jenny' and LastName = 'Earhart')

--alter table #Person drop column ID

set @SupervisorID = (Select PersonID from #Person where FirstName = 'Supervisor' AND LastName = 'One')
set @SupervisorNode = (SELECT PersonNode from #PersonOrg where PersonID = @SupervisorID)

---query goes here
select 
    p.FirstName  + ' ' + p.LastName as Employee, spouse.FirstName + ' ' + spouse.LastName as Spouse, p.EmployedOn as pEmp, spouse.EmployedOn as sEmp, o.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) as pAncestor, @SupervisorNode as Ancestor, so.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) as sAncestor,
    CASE when spouse.PersonID is not null THEN p.FirstName + ' & ' + spouse.FirstName +  ' ' + p.LastName
        else p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as EmployeeName
    --spouse.PersonID as SpouseID,

from #Person p
left join #PersonOrg o on p.PersonID = o.PersonID
left join #PersonRelationship pr on p.PersonID = pr.PersonID
left join #Person spouse on pr.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
left join #PersonOrg so on spouse.PersonID = so.PersonID

WHERE (o.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) = @SupervisorNode --this is a must
        OR so.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) = @SupervisorNode
)
and (p.EmployedOn < spouse.EmployedOn OR spouse.PersonID is null)
ORDER BY p.ID

drop table #PersonOrg
drop table #PersonRelationship
drop table #Person
```

Please consider the following image:
[image: test]

Here's what I want to point out for couples:

**Couple 1:**

There is no tricky part here since they are both under same Supervisor

`(pAncestor and sAncestor = Ancestor)`. We just get the first one employed. In this case, ***John Doe***.
So `EmployeeName` should be ***'John & Jane Doe'***

**Couple 2:**

Notice that they have different ancestors and ***Sherry Wayne*** has been employed first than ***John Wayne***. But we only want to consider the employee under the ancestor.

So EmployeeName should be ***'John & Sherry Wayne'*** since **John** is the empoloyee under the specified supervisor even though **Sherry** has been employed first.

**Couple 3:**

Not too tricky, they only have different Last Names. We just use the lastname of the first one employed. EmployeeName should be: ***'Carl & Jenny Malone'***

As you notice in the sample query I included, Couple 2 is off the mark since it shows `Sherry & John Wayne` instead of `John & Sherry Wayne`.

***EDIT:** Here is the result of the query I included in  the script:

[image: result]

Please help guys. Thanks.

Comment: Please, could you add the desired result?

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood completely your request.  But I modified your query as follow (added an internal CASE):

```
CASE when spouse.PersonID is not null 
        THEN CASE WHEN o.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1)= @SupervisorNode  THEN p.FirstName + ' & ' + spouse.FirstName +  ' ' + p.LastName
                  ELSE spouse.FirstName + ' & ' + p.FirstName +  ' ' + p.LastName 
              END
        else p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as EmployeeName
```

**Or (after your comment that give other specs) this other (I modified only the WHERE conditions):**

```
select 
    p.FirstName  + ' ' + p.LastName as Employee, spouse.FirstName + ' ' + spouse.LastName as Spouse, p.EmployedOn as pEmp, spouse.EmployedOn as sEmp
    , o.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) as pAncestor, @SupervisorNode as Ancestor, so.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) as sAncestor,
    CASE when spouse.PersonID is not null THEN p.FirstName + ' & ' + spouse.FirstName +  ' ' + p.LastName
        else p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as EmployeeName
    --spouse.PersonID as SpouseID,
from #Person p
left join #PersonOrg o on p.PersonID = o.PersonID
left join #PersonRelationship pr on p.PersonID = pr.PersonID
left join #Person spouse on pr.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
left join #PersonOrg so on spouse.PersonID = so.PersonID

WHERE ((o.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) = @SupervisorNode  and (p.EmployedOn < spouse.EmployedOn OR spouse.PersonID is null))
        )
        OR ( so.PersonNode.GetAncestor(1) <> @SupervisorNode and p.EmployedOn >= spouse.EmployedOn  )
ORDER BY p.ID
```

Output (ometted ancestor columns):

```
Employee                                 Spouse                                   pEmp                    sEmp                    EmployeeName
---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------------------------
John Doe                                 Jane Doe                                 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 John & Jane Doe
Sherry Wayne                             John Wayne                               2012-01-12 00:00:00.000 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 John & Sherry Wayne
Carl Malone                              Jenny Earhart                            2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 Carl & Jenny Malone
Tom No Wife                              NULL                                     2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Tom No Wife
Cherry Irrelevant                        NULL                                     2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Cherry Irrelevant
Eric Morales                             NULL                                     2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Eric Morales
Sheldon Marley                           NULL                                     2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Sheldon Marley
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid nested cases as there are more conditions I need to perform after successfully fetching the correct names, well using nested cases (which I already know how to that's why I haven't included it in the question). So, additional nested cases would impact on performance. Thanks anyway.

Comment: nailed it! ^^, thanks.. just change `>=` condition to `>` (don't think there'll be duplicate datetime.